# Why this template structure (specialization) won't compile in VS 2022?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, module, c++20

This code will not compile with MSVC, it contains template specialization in C++ 20 spirit. Could someone help? The code contains template specialization and is using modules, but it will not work.

```cpp
//Grid.cppm
export module grid;

export import :main;
export import :string;
```

```cpp
//GridMain.cppm
module;

#include <cstddef>

export module grid:main;

import <stdexcept>;
import <vector>;
import <optional>;
import <utility>;
import <format>;

export
template <typename T>
class Grid
{
public:
    explicit Grid(size_t width = DefaultWidth, size_t height = DefaultHeight);
    virtual ~Grid() = default;

    // Explicitly default a copy constructor and copy assignment operator.
    Grid(const Grid& src) = default;
    Grid& operator=(const Grid& rhs) = default;

    // Explicitly default a move constructor and move assignment operator.
    Grid(Grid&& src) = default;
    Grid& operator=(Grid&& rhs) = default;

    std::optional<T>& at(size_t x, size_t y);
    const std::optional<T>& at(size_t x, size_t y) const;

    size_t getHeight() const { return m_height; }
    size_t getWidth() const { return m_width; }

    static const size_t DefaultWidth{ 10 };
    static const size_t DefaultHeight{ 10 };

private:
    void verifyCoordinate(size_t x, size_t y) const;

    std::vector<std::vector<std::optional<T>>> m_cells;
    size_t m_width{ 0 }, m_height{ 0 };
};

template <typename T>
Grid<T>::Grid(size_t width, size_t height)
    : m_width{ width }
    , m_height{ height }
{
    m_cells.resize(m_width);
    for (auto& column : m_cells) {
        column.resize(m_height);
    }
}

template <typename T>
void Grid<T>::verifyCoordinate(size_t x, size_t y) const
{
    if (x >= m_width) {
        throw std::out_of_range{ std::format("{} must be less than {}.", x, m_width) };
    }
    if (y >= m_height) {
        throw std::out_of_range{ std::format("{} must be less than {}.", y, m_height) };
    }
}

template <typename T>
const std::optional<T>& Grid<T>::at(size_t x, size_t y) const
{
    verifyCoordinate(x, y);
    return m_cells[x][y];
}

template <typename T>
std::optional<T>& Grid<T>::at(size_t x, size_t y)
{
    return const_cast<std::optional<T>&>(std::as_const(*this).at(x, y));
}
```

```cpp
//GridString.cppm

module;

#include <cstddef>

export module grid:string;

import <stdexcept>;
import <vector>;
import <optional>;
import <utility>;
import <string>;
import <format>;

// When the template specialization is used, the original template must be
// visible too.
import :main;

export
template <>
class Grid<const char*>
{
public:
    explicit Grid(size_t width = DefaultWidth, size_t height = DefaultHeight);
    virtual ~Grid() = default;

    // Explicitly default a copy constructor and copy assignment operator.
    Grid(const Grid& src) = default;
    Grid& operator=(const Grid& rhs) = default;

    // Explicitly default a move constructor and move assignment operator.
    Grid(Grid&& src) = default;
    Grid& operator=(Grid&& rhs) = default;

    std::optional<std::string>& at(size_t x, size_t y);
    const std::optional<std::string>& at(size_t x, size_t y) const;

    size_t getHeight() const { return m_height; }
    size_t getWidth() const { return m_width; }

    static const size_t DefaultWidth{ 10 };
    static const size_t DefaultHeight{ 10 };

private:
    void verifyCoordinate(size_t x, size_t y) const;

    std::vector<std::vector<std::optional<std::string>>> m_cells;
    size_t m_width{ 0 }, m_height{ 0 };
};

Grid<const char*>::Grid(size_t width, size_t height)
    : m_width{ width }
    , m_height{ height }
{
    m_cells.resize(m_width);
    for (auto& column : m_cells) {
        column.resize(m_height);
    }
}

void Grid<const char*>::verifyCoordinate(size_t x, size_t y) const
{
    if (x >= m_width) {
        throw std::out_of_range{ std::format("{} must be less than {}.", x, m_width) };
    }
    if (y >= m_height) {
        throw std::out_of_range{ std::format("{} must be less than {}.", y, m_height) };
    }
}

const std::optional<std::string>& Grid<const char*>::at(size_t x, size_t y) const
{
    verifyCoordinate(x, y);
    return m_cells[x][y];
}

std::optional<std::string>& Grid<const char*>::at(size_t x, size_t y)
{
    return const_cast<std::optional<std::string>&>(std::as_const(*this).at(x, y));
}
```

```cpp
//GridTest.cpp

import <iostream>;
import <string>;
import grid;

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Grid<int> myIntGrid;                    // Uses original Grid template.
    Grid<const char*> stringGrid1{ 2, 2 };  // Uses const char* specialization.

    const char* dummy{ "dummy" };
    stringGrid1.at(0, 0) = "hello";
    stringGrid1.at(0, 1) = dummy;
    stringGrid1.at(1, 0) = dummy;
    stringGrid1.at(1, 1) = "there";

    Grid<const char*> stringGrid2{ stringGrid1 };

    cout << stringGrid1.at(0, 1).value_or("") << endl;
    cout << stringGrid2.at(0, 1).value_or("") << endl;
}
```

The code contains grid structure and it performs specialization in order to obtain the working grid and testing in module cpp...

Comment: Is that really a [mre], with emphasis on the ***minimal*** part? And even if the error messages tend to become long when templates are involved, please [edit] your question to include the complete build-log, copy-pasted as text.

Comment: What error did you encounter?

Comment: It says it cannot find module grid... All  settings were set-up, latest standard etc...

Comment: The MS compiler expects the module interface to use a `.ixx` extension. If you use `.cppm` instead, you probably need to use the "Compile as" setting to inform the compiler.

Comment: I am using option compile as internal partition, not as interface in order not to use ixx extension.

Comment: This desperately needs a [mcve], and the error message added to the question.

Comment: Yes, error message and build commandlines would have both been necessary to diagnose this issue without prescient insight – please keep in mind for future questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am using option compile as internal partition, not as interface

Use /interface  instead of  internal partition. You may have misunderstood /interface.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/interface?view=msvc-170

> Use this switch when a module interface has a different extension than
> .ixx.
>
> In the following example, the module interface has a .cppm extension
> instead of .ixx, so the /interface switch is used to compile it as a
> module interface:

Comment: Perfect! It is working now! I managed to get the solution running! Thanks so much!